# From a DDD perspective, how to handle DB specific types?

Tags: go, design-patterns, google-cloud-firestore, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement DDD in my project and I'm using Firestore as my persistence infrastructure. Firestore in Go has some specific types like `*firestore.DocumentRef`.

I think that I should put it in my *entity* struct as it should represent my model, but my entity should also be db agnostic (I think).

So how should I handle from a DDD perspective this entity/struct:

```golang
    type Holder struct {
        SocialReason       string                 `firestore:"social_reason" json:"social_reason"`
        Contact            value.Contact          `firestore:"contact" json:"contact"`
        Location           value.Location         `firestore:"location" json:"location"`
        SubmissionDatetime time.Time              `firestore:"submission_datetime" json:"-"`
        UpdateDatetime     time.Time              `firestore:"update_datetime" json:"-"`
        Status             string                 `firestore:"status" json:"status"`
        LastModifier       *firestore.DocumentRef `firestore:"last_modifier" json:"-"`
        CEP                string                 `firestore:"cep,omitempty" json:"cep,omitempty"`
        Country            string                 `firestore:"country" json:"country"`
        Region             string                 `firestore:"region,omitempty" json:"region,omitempty"`
        City               string                 `firestore:"city,omitempty" json:"city,omitempty"`
    }
```

Comment: I'd not put db specific types in my application structs. I'd convert them in the db layer.

Comment: Would you suggest use an interface{} instead of the type itself then?

Comment: Why store a DocumentRef? Use it to get the data you need and throw it away. At least that's what I would do.

Comment: It is useful as a foreign key sort of thing. Speeds up things when querying values.

Comment: Question is what do you want / need. If you want to be independent of a specific data source it would be a nightmare to have DocumentRef in your models if you ever need to switch or need to implement a secondary data source. If you need every bit of performance it is different. But are you sure you need it or is this premature optimization? An interface could be a compromise between speed and independance.

Comment: Good point. I think for now it's just not worth the headache

Comment: @nicolasassi What's the alternative, storing a `UserId` for instance? You could easily query holders and then query all users in one go providing all IDs as a filter criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid having any kind of implementation-specific technology choices represented in your Domain, unless - possibly, but not likely - they are *truly part of* the Ubiquitous Language of said domain (which is not the case in your example, it seems).

There's a great blog series about implementing DDD using Golang, with an accompanying codebase that is evolved as the series introduces ever more DDD-related concepts. Check the [Wild Workouts](https://github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/wild-workouts-go-ddd-example) example.

You can directly learn from this code, as they are also using Firebase as one of the storage implementations in their [Ports and Adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) architecture. They also have SQL and InMemory (useful for testing) storage implementations.

So, how do they represent `firestore.DocumentRef` outside of the repository impl? Well, as a simple `string`. See for example [GetUser()](https://github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/wild-workouts-go-ddd-example/blob/22c0a25b67c4669d612a2fa4a434ffae8e35e65a/internal/users/firestore.go#L31) ..

/internal/users/firestore.go

```golang
type db struct {
    firestoreClient *firestore.Client
}

func (d db) GetUser(ctx context.Context, userID string) (UserModel, error) {
    doc, err := d.UserDocumentRef(userID).Get(ctx)

    // More stuff to get the user model.
}
```

Important to note that for user management they do not use DDD, but basic CRUD (with their simple use cases for user management they have chosen to forego the extra complexity that DDD would introduce).

Examples of full DDD design are in the Trainer and Training domains. There's a bit more complexity here (e.g. in handling transactions), so I refer to [The Repository pattern: a painless way to simplify your Go service logic](https://threedots.tech/post/repository-pattern-in-go/) that explains these concepts.

But you can clearly see how things are split up between domain concept (repository interface) and implementation (repository adapter). For instance in the Trainings domain, implementing `Hour`:

- /internal/trainer/domain/hour/repository.go --> [GetHour()](https://github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/wild-workouts-go-ddd-example/blob/22c0a25b67c4669d612a2fa4a434ffae8e35e65a/internal/trainer/domain/hour/repository.go#L9)
- /internal/trainer/adapters/hour_firestore_repository.go --> [GetHour()](https://github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/wild-workouts-go-ddd-example/blob/22c0a25b67c4669d612a2fa4a434ffae8e35e65a/internal/trainer/adapters/hour_firestore_repository.go#L30)

Comment: I do have a quesiton: how abstract should the interface be? Should we put more logic in the storage layer or app layer? For example `GetItemsForBob(bid)` or `GetItemAForBob` and `GetItemBForBob` and merge item A and B together at the app layer? What if I have ten items that I need to merge.

Comment: Valid questions, but also not possible to answer as there's no one generic approach. These considerations can be both app- and domain-specific and depend on requirements and the tech stack you have. They are the typical ones you encounter in the elaboration of any project and you have to weigh the pros and cons. Although in your example the `ForBob` seems awfully specific, unless Bob is part of your domain.

Comment: Hmm Let's say we have a domain model `Menu` that encapsulates `[]Drink` `[]Food` `[]Alcohol` etc.. I guess my question is : Should we just call `repo.GetMenu(mid)` at the app layer and let the storage layer to fetch the food,  alcohol and drink and map it to the domain object. OR keeping the storage layer simple by calling `GetMenu` `GetDrinks` `GetFood` at the app layer and aggregate them together at the app layer. But I guess you are right, it is probably just a design choice, if you need the granularity a lot in the app layer, maybe granular is better. if not, abstract might be better.

Comment: Yes, it is still a design decision. If there was a simple relational model between Menu and the other entities then a GetMenu may be best choice. But there might be more complex business rules, and even domain logic involved in 'hydrating' the Menu aggregate root. Such as available ingredients, amount still in storage, food preferences (e.g. vegan), etc.